# How to open a page in new tab on click of a button in react? I want to send some data to that page also

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm working on a raise invoice page, in which user can raise a invoice on clicking of a button, I would call a api call and after getting the response I want to send some data to a **page**(RaisedInvoice.jsx) which should open in a **new tab**, how can i do it. The thing which I am not getting is how to open a page in new tab on click of a button in **ReactJs**.

RaiseInvoice.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import Links from './Links.jsx';
import history from './history.jsx';

import axios from 'axios';

class RaiseInvoice extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
        this.state = {projects: [], searchParam : ''};
        this.raiseInvoiceClicked = this.raiseInvoiceClicked.bind(this);
    }
    
    raiseInvoiceClicked(){
        // here i wish to write the code for opening the page in new tab.
    }
    
    render() {
      return (
         <div>
              <Links activeTabName="tab2"></Links>
              <div className="container">
                  <div className = "row col-md-4">
                      <h1>Raise Invoice...</h1>
                  </div>
                  <div className = "row col-md-4"></div>
                  <div className = "row col-md-4" style ={{"marginTop":"24px"}}>
                      <button type="button" className="btn btn-default pull-right" onClick={this.raiseInvoiceClicked}>Raise Invoice</button>
                  </div>
                  
              </div>
         </div>
      )
    }
}

export default RaiseInvoice;
```

Comment: which version of react-router do you use ?

Comment: what kind of data?

Comment: "react-router": "^4.1.2" @jayabalaji j

Comment: I have to send an array of data to display them in a table, and some other details like address headings etc.....

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Since you were going to send big data, appending them to your target URL looks shabby.  I would suggest you use 'LocalStorage' for this purpose.  So your code looks like this,

```
raiseInvoiceClicked(){
   // your axios call here
   localStorage.setItem("pageData", "Data Retrieved from axios request")
   // route to new page by changing window.location
   window.open(newPageUrl, "_blank") //to open new page
}
```

In your RaisedInvoice.jsx, retrieve the data from Local Storage like this,

```
componentWillMount() {
  localStorage.pagedata= "your Data";
  // set the data in state and use it through the component
  localStorage.removeItem("pagedata");
  // removing the data from localStorage.  Since if user clicks for another invoice it overrides this data
}
```

Comment: this will only work if the link is not to a different site

Comment: I'm getting this error: 
Unknown prop params on <a> tag. Remove this prop from the element.
@jayabalaji j

Comment: can you explain me where and how to use this # ??

Comment: I have updated the code using local storage..pls check

Answer (score 31):

You can just use plain JS to do it and append some query perimeters with it

```
raiseInvoiceClicked(){
    const url = 'somesite.com?data=yourDataToSend';
    window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```

Comment: i used to do like this:
history.push({
            pathname: '/editProject',
            state: { projectData : projectData}
        })
but is there any way to open in a new tab...?

Comment: if its in the same domain use @Jayabalaji J answer, if its in another domain then you dont have many options to pass the data. url params are the only way

Comment: how to access the data from the url in the newly opened react component?? @joey

Comment: heres a post that gives you a helper method to extract the params from the URL. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 8):

Instead of calling raiseInvoiceClicked() function inside onclick method, you can try

```
onClick="window.open('your_url')"
```

in your code.

Comment: it will not work , i think it will give you the error of assigning string into the event

Comment: If you want this approche you can't pass string, you need a function like this:  `onClick={() => window.open("your_url")}`

Answer (score 3):

Simply do this!

```js
const openLinkInNewTab = ( url ) => {
  const newTab = window.open(url, '_blank', 'noopener,noreferrer');
  if ( newTab ) newTab.opener = null;
}
//...

  return (
         //...
         <button onClick={ () => openLinkInNewTab('your.url')}> Click Here </button>
         //...
        )
```

Answer (score -1):

Pass this data with props:

```js
let href = '...url_to_redirect...'; let data_to_send = [...];

let api_href = '...url_api_where_sent_data.../?data_to_send';
export const DictDefaultOptions = (url=(api_href), method='GET') => {
let defaultOptions = {
    url : url,
    method  : method,
    mode : 'cors',
    headers : {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'}
};

return defaultOptions };

let sentData = { 
    method: defaultOptions.method, 
    mode: defaultOptions.mode 
};

send_data_to_api = () => {
    let api_return = await fetch(api_href, sentData)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseText => { 
            data = (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(responseText))) 
        })
        .catch(error => { 
            console.log(`${requestURL} error: `, error)
        });

    do { await this.wait(100) } while(Object.keys(api_return).length <= 0);

    if (Object.keys(api_return).length > 0) {
        return window.open(href, "_blank")
    } 
};
```

Comment: man, i think this s the best and complete way... editor makes the code not so good to understand, but i aways do like that ... a little gift this piece of code ... React APP JS

Answer (score -1):

## You can open it in a new window using the following code.

#### Please note that for props you can pass any child components that should be rendered inside new window.

```
const RenderInWindow = (props) => {
  const [container, setContainer] = useState(null);
  const newWindow = useRef(null);
useEffect(() => {
    // Create container element on client-side
    setContainer(document.createElement("div"));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // When container is ready
    if (container) {
      // Create window
      newWindow.current = window.open(
        "",
        "",
        "width=600,height=400,left=200,top=200"
      );
      // Append container
      newWindow.current.document.body.appendChild(container);

      // Save reference to window for cleanup
      const curWindow = newWindow.current;

      // Return cleanup function
      return () => curWindow.close();
    }
  }, [container]);

  return container && createPortal(props.children, container);
};
```